# How to load form

Tags: c#, winforms

In c# I'm working on a project and I try to make the program go to another form it does but its blank

Code:

```
   Form form2 = new Form();
   form2.Show();
```

Comment: You are making an instance of the default `Form`. To show a form with a UI, you need to make your own form and show that.

Comment: @MatthewJ : What is the actual name of the Form that you want to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making an instance of `Form` class which is the base class and should be blank.

Define your `Form` object like this instead:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

Or

```
Form form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll accept you answer in a minute it says I have to wait.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a object of the **form 2** like this

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.show();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

you are creating a new instance of the base class Form from which your application forms are deriving.

saying you have two forms in your application, Form1 and Form2, to show Form2 from Form1 do this:

```
var myForm2 = new Form2();
myForm2.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

A new Form instance is just blank. You have to create an instance of your own customized Form (Form2?) and show.

May be like below.

```
// Create and display a modless Form2.
Form2 myForm = new Form2();
myForm.Show();
```

Look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) for more Form.Show() examples.

Comment: Side note: if you want the myForm to be a popup, and require the user to perform an action before returning, you can use myForm.ShowDialog()

Comment: Here is MSDN page for ShowDialog() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(v=vs.71).aspx